# Using Linq Except to return items deleted from a list but have the same Id

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following lists:

```
var previousRun = new List<Data>();
var currentRun = new List<Data>();

var item1= new Data() { Id = "1", Address = "Test Address", Name = "Test", PostCode = "ABC DEF" };
var item2 = new Data() { Id = "2", Address = "Test Address2", Name = "Test2", PostCode = "GHI JKL" };

var item1Updated = new Data() { Id = "1", Address = "UpdatedAddress", Name = "UpdatedTest", PostCode = "STU VWX" };
var item2Updated= new Data() { Id = "2", Address = "UpdatedAddress2", Name = "Test2", PostCode = "TES TIN" };

previousRun.Add(item1);
previousRun.Add(item2);

currentRun.Add(item1updated);
currentRun.Add(item2updated);
```

I am trying to count the number of items that have been deleted from the previous list in the current list:

```
public DataChange<Data>[] Compare(Data[] previous, Data[] current)
{
    var deletedResults = previous
        .Except(current)
        .Select(DataChange<Data>.Deleted)
        .ToList();
}
```

In this scenario, I want the result to be 0 as nothing has been deleted, only updated (I appreciate that it could be argued that the originals have been 'deleted' but I will also have a list of updated items, so deleted really means that the IDs have been deleted.

Instead `deletedResults` is 2, as it believes both the original items have been removed. Can anyone please help with a Linq query that will only show items as 'deleted' if the Ids are in the previous list but not the current one.

**UPDATE**

I have implemented an EqualityComparer as suggested in the comments:

```
public class DataEqualityComparer: IEqualityComparer<GpLookupData>
    {
        public bool Equals(Data previous, Data current)
        {
            var idComparer = string.Equals(previous.Id, current.Id, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 
            var nameComparer = string.Equals(previous.Name, current.Name, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            var addressComparer = string.Equals(previous.Address, current.Address, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            var postcodeComparer = string.Equals(previous.PostCode, current.PostCode, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 
          

            if (idComparer && nameComparer && addressComparer && postcodeComparer) 
            {
                return true; 
            }

            return false; 
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Data obj)
        {
            return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should implement an IEqualityComparer for your Data object and pass it on Except.

Comment: It's kind of tough with `Except()` since the objects in the previous and current lists aren't the same. You could create a class that implements `IEqualityComparer<Data>` to pass to `Except()`, but it might just be easier to do something like this: `var deletedResults = previousRun.Where(d => !currentRun.Select(d2 => d2.Id).Contains(d.Id)).ToList();`

Comment: IEqualityComparer is the way to go. Where/Contains will have O(N²) complexity

Comment: Thank you @RogersonNazário - I have implemented an IEqualityComparer but am still having the same issue - I have updated my answer to show my EqualityComparer - do you have any thoughts on where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Thank you @itsme86 - I have implemented an IEqualityComparer but am still having the same issue - I have updated my answer to show my EqualityComparer - do you have any thoughts on where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Your `GetHashCode` is not consistent with `Equals` - two objects that have the same name but differ in casing are "equal" (if other properties are equal as well) but will have different hash codes. Try `obj.Name.ToLower().GetHashCode()`

Comment: Also, your "equality" is checking several properties, but in your question you only seem interested in duplicate IDs. Why don;t you just create an equality comparer that only looks at ID?

Comment: Thank you @DStanley, I have updated the `GetHashCode`. Sorry if my original question was misleading. I'm saying that if they have duplicate IDs, but have been updated (e.g. updated address) I don't want them to count as 'deleted' items. They should only be deleted if all of that info (id, name, address) etc no longer exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> deleted really means that the IDs have been deleted.

So it sounds like you want all IDs that are in list 1 but not list 2.

You don't need `Except` and an equality comparer for that - just do:

```
var deleted = previousRun.Where(p => !currentRun.Any(c => c.Id == p.Id));
```

If you need a little better performance you can create a hash set from the "current" IDs:

```
var idList = new HashSet<int>(currentRun.Select(c => C.Id));
var deleted = previousRun.Where(p => idList.Contains(p.Id));
```

Answer (score 0):

`.Except()` will use the default equality comparer if a `IEqualityComparer<T>` has not been specified.

The default equality comparer will use the following logic:

1. If the type implements `IEquatable<T>`, use the `bool Equals(T other)` method
2. If the type overrides `bool Equals(object)`, use that.
3. If the type is a reference type, use `ReferenceEquals(object, object)`. If the type is a value type, each field in the type will be compared.

My guess is that the Data-type is a reference type that does not override any equals method, so reference equality will be used. So you would need to define how the objects are compared.

If you implement/override any of the equals methods, keep in mind to also override  the `GetHashCode()` method.

Comment: Thank you @JonasH- I have implemented an IEqualityComparer but am still having the same issue - I have updated my answer to show my EqualityComparer - do you have any thoughts on where I've gone wrong?

Comment: @jordan1993 In your examples the updated data have different name, Address and postcode. If you want to consider item1 and item1updated to be equal you should only compare the Id in your equalitycomparer.